# Check if two lists are in one pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two lists which contain terms in strings format. Those terms belong to two categories: fruits and vehicles. I am trying to display a dataframe only containing pairs of terms from conflicting categories. What would be the best approach to do that? Below is an example of my list and a dataframe. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
  dataframe:

         col 1                 
  ['apple', 'truck' ]
  ['truck', 'orange']
  ['pear',  'motorcycle']
  ['pear', 'orange' ]
  ['apple', 'pear'  ]
  ['truck', 'car'   ]


  vehicles = ['car', 'truck', 'motorcycle']
  fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear']


  desired output:

        col 2

  ['apple', 'truck' ]
  ['pear', 'motorcycle']
  ['truck', 'orange']
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create `DataFrame` from lists column, test membership by [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html), then invert masks by `~`, check at least one `True` per row with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for both lists and last chain conditions by bitwise AND - `&` with filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['col 1'].values.tolist())
df = df[(~df1.isin(vehicles)).any(axis=1) & (~df1.isin(fruits)).any(axis=1)]
print (df)
                col 1
0      [apple, truck]
1     [truck, orange]
2  [pear, motorcycle]
```

Another solution with intersection of `set`s chained by `and` (because scalars) and cast to `bool` - empty sets are converted to `False`:

```
def func(x):
    s = set(x)
    v = set(vehicles)
    f = set(fruits)
    return bool((s & v) and (s & f))

df = df[df['col 1'].apply(func)]
print (df)
                col 1
0      [apple, truck]
1     [truck, orange]
2  [pear, motorcycle]
```

Answer (score 0):

May be `np.isin` could be useful for you!

```
super_set = np.array([vehicles,fruits])

def f(x):
    return all(np.isin(super_set,x).sum(axis=1))

df[df.col1.apply(f)]

#
col1
0   [apple, truck]
1   [truck, orange]
2   [pear, motorcycle]
```